# H2 MERGE: Column not found

Tags: h2, sql-merge

I've got the following table:

```
create table companies (id identity, version int not null, last_modified timestamp not null);
insert into companies (version, last_modified) values (0, NOW());
```

I then create a `PreparedStatement` and supply a value for index 1:

```
merge into companies (id, version, last_modified) values(?, version + 1, NOW())
```

H2 fails with this error:

```
Column "VERSION" not found
```

I understand that H2 doesn't like `version + 1` on the right-hand side, but it's not clear how to return 0 for new rows and `version + 1` for existing rows. Is there an easier way than using a `select` statement with a `union`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
merge into companies (id, version, last_modified) 
values(?, coalesce((select version + 1 from companies where id = ?), 0), NOW())
```

Comment: Excellent answer as always. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thomas's answer of

```
merge into companies (id, version, last_modified) 
values(?, coalesce((select version + 1 from companies where id = ?), 0), NOW())
```

Becomes rather cumbersome if you (as I do) want to conditionally insert or update several fields - you need a coalesce((select ...), default) for each one!

It would appear that a more general answer needs to be two statements:

```
MERGE INTO companies (id) key (id) VALUES (?)
UPDATE companies SET version=1+IFNULL(version,0), otherfields... WHERE id=?
```

In other words: don't use MERGE for multiple conditional changes (where you need an expression and not just a value) in a record.

I'd love to be proven wrong on this...